# How to add polymers unresolved attribute to body tag in meteor project?

Tags: meteor, polymer

I am new to both polymer and meteor. Polymer is working fine in meteor project by.

```
meteor create project
cd project
bower init
bower install --save Polymer/polymer
bower install --save Polymer/webcomponentsjs
bower install --save Polymer/core-elements
bower install --save Polymer/paper-elements
```

then moved *bower_components* directory to *public* directory. Then import polymer elements by

```
<script src="bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.js"></script>
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/core-drawer-panel/core-drawer-panel.html">
```

Now I need to add **unresolved** attributes to **body** tag. When I tried `<body unresolved>` meteor says

```
While building the application:
project.html:20: Parse error in tag
```

Whats the proper way to include unresolved attribute to body?

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer myself. It might be helpful for someone. Add below code inside your `Meteor.isClient`

```
Meteor.startup(function() {
  $('body').attr('unresolved', 'true');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this is a HTML parser error, try `unresolved="true"`.

Comment: When I tried unresolved="true" meteor says "Attributes on <body> not supported"

Comment: Then you should fill an issue with Meteor. I can't understand why they would not allow someone to able an attribute on <body> tag.

Comment: I found an answer. checkout my answer above